# Função Javascript que gera cores html conforme valor

Tags: javascript, html, cores

Preciso criar uma função em Javascript que recebe um int e retorna um código de cores html. A regra é: Quanto menor o número mais "fria" é a cor gerada (azul claro, por exemplo) e quanto maior mais quente. Porém os valores devem seguir um degradê de tal forma que a cor gerada para o número 1 seja bem parecida, porém diferente da cor gerada para o número 2.

Assuma que os valores aceitáveis pela função estejam no intervalo [0, 100]

Comment: Cara faz com que sua função retorne o código das cores.
Aqui um site onde vc pode pegar alguns códigos de cores como exemplo pra ver o quanto será necessário para realizar o degrade que vc deseja, [Cores](http://www.ufpa.br/dicas/htm/htm-cor1.htm)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Criei esta função básica, que talvez atenda à sua necessidade:

```
function colorTween(c1,c2,p) {
  var r1 = parseInt(c1.substring(1,3),16);
  var g1 = parseInt(c1.substring(3,5),16);
  var b1 = parseInt(c1.substring(5,7),16);
  var r2 = parseInt(c2.substring(1,3),16);
  var g2 = parseInt(c2.substring(3,5),16);
  var b2 = parseInt(c2.substring(5,7),16);
  var r3 = (256+(r2-r1)*p/100+r1).toString(16);
  var g3 = (256+(g2-g1)*p/100+g1).toString(16);
  var b3 = (256+(b2-b1)*p/100+b1).toString(16);
  return '#'+r3.substring(1,3)+g3.substring(1,3)+b3.substring(1,3);
}
```

Ela pode ser otimizada, conforme a necessidade específica sua, mas a sintaxe é basicamente neste formato:

```
colorTween( '#000000', '#ffffff', 50 )
```

sendo o primeiro parâmetro, a cor equivalente a zero, o segundo, equivalente a 100, e o terceiro, a porcentagem desejada de mistura.

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/jw5ugb33/)**.

**Simplificando, caso as cores sejam "fixas":**

```
function colorTween(p) {
  var r1 = 0xff;
  var g1 = 0x00;
  var b1 = 0x00;
  var r2 = 0xaa;
  var g2 = 0x33;
  var b2 = 0xfc;
  var r3 = (256+(r2-r1)*p/100+r1).toString(16);
  var g3 = (256+(g2-g1)*p/100+g1).toString(16);
  var b3 = (256+(b2-b1)*p/100+b1).toString(16);
  return '#'+r3.substring(1,3)+g3.substring(1,3)+b3.substring(1,3);
}
```

neste caso, basta colocar os valores em RGB diretamente nas variáveis r1, g1, b1 e r2, g2, b2 respectivamente (ou substituir diretamente na fórmula).

Para usar esta versão, basta fornecer a porcentagem desejada, neste formato:

```
colorTween( 50 )
```

Veja funcionando no **[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bacco/rjvwzfp4/)**.

**Sobre degradês:**

Já foge um pouco da amplitude da pergunta, mas vale mencionar o seguinte: esta função faz a conversão linear no espaço RGB. Para efeitos de arco-íris, e degradês com cores mais variadas, pode-se aplicar conversão no espaço HSV ou LAB. O que é uma questão mais de matemática do que de JS, mas pode valer à pena caso o design da aplicação comporte.

Comment: Muito obrigado @Bacco :)