# Tonalidade da cor do registro, referente a quantidade

Tags: php

Tenho uma tabela com **vários registros**, e estes possuem um campo "**data**".

Gero uma lista desses registros, faço a diferença de dias comparando a "**data**" com a "**data atual**". Exemplo:

```
$dias = $data_hoje - $data_registro;
```

Defino 2 cores. Exemplo: **branco, preto**, exemplo:

```
$cor1 = '#FFF';
$cor2 = '#000';
```

Gero um **valor padrão** da "**data mais antiga**" dos registros com a "**data atual**". Exemplo:

```
$data_padrão = $data_hoje - $data_primeiro_registro;
$data_final = $data_hoje;
```

O que gostaria é: imprimir a lista, trazendo a **intensidade** das cores, conforme os dias corridos em relação ao **valor padrão** calculado. Essa intensidade, seria na escala do "degradê" desse intervalo de cor.

Como eu faço para gerar essa cor com a intensidade relacionada ao registro  as 3 variáveis que possuo (data mais antiga, hoje, data do registro) ?

Tenho que usar `decimal` e depois transformar para `hexa` ? Ou posso usar `hexa`, ou outra forma de cor ?

Comment: Em JS tem isso aqui: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/97277/fun%c3%a7%c3%a3o-javascript-que-gera-cores-html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro, vamos criar uma função que dada uma cor que corresponde ao valor 0, uma cor que corresponde ao valor 1 e um valor entre 0 e 1, forneça a cor correspondente:

```
function interpolar_cor($cor0, $cor1, $valor) {
    if ($valor <= 0) return $cor0;
    if ($valor >= 1) return $cor1;
    list($r0, $g0, $b0) = sscanf($cor0, "#%02x%02x%02x");
    list($r1, $g1, $b1) = sscanf($cor1, "#%02x%02x%02x");
    $rx = (int) ($valor * ($r1 - $r0) + $r0);
    $gx = (int) ($valor * ($g1 - $g0) + $g0);
    $bx = (int) ($valor * ($b1 - $b0) + $b0);
    return "#" . str_pad(dechex($rx * 256 * 256 + $gx * 256 + $bx), 6, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT);
}
```

As cores devem ter o formato `#rrggbb` onde `rr` é o valor hexadecimal do componente vermelho, `gg` o do componente verde e `bb` o do componente azul.

Feito isso, podemos criar uma função para interpolar datas e associá-las à cores:

```
function interpolar_cor_data($cor0, $data0, $cor1, $data1, $dataX) {
    $dias_max = $data1->diff($data0)->days;
    if ($dias_max <= 0) $dias_max = 1;
    $dias_t = $dataX->diff($data0)->days;
    return interpolar_cor($cor0, $cor1, $dias_t / (float) $dias_max);
}
```

Vamos fazer um teste. Primeiro, vamos definir algumas datas:

```
$data_teste1 = new DateTime("2018-04-01");
$data_teste2 = new DateTime("2018-04-05");
$data_teste3 = new DateTime("2018-04-10");
$data_teste4 = new DateTime("2018-04-20");
$data_teste5 = new DateTime("2018-04-30");
$data_teste6 = new DateTime("2018-05-04");

$data_hoje = new DateTime("2018-05-04");
$data_inicio = new DateTime("2018-04-01");
```

E então, testá-las com as cores branco sendo o ponto 0 e preto o ponto 1:

```
// Entre branco e preto:
$branco = "#ffffff";
$preto = "#000000";
echo interpolar_cor_data($branco, $data_inicio, $preto, $data_hoje, $data_teste1) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($branco, $data_inicio, $preto, $data_hoje, $data_teste2) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($branco, $data_inicio, $preto, $data_hoje, $data_teste3) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($branco, $data_inicio, $preto, $data_hoje, $data_teste4) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($branco, $data_inicio, $preto, $data_hoje, $data_teste5) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($branco, $data_inicio, $preto, $data_hoje, $data_teste6) . "\n";
```

A saída é:

```
#ffffff
#e0e0e0
#b9b9b9
#6c6c6c
#1e1e1e
#000000
```

Ou seja, na saída deu essas cores: [image: 50 tons de cinza]

Vamos tentar com outras cores. Vermelho para o ponto 0 e verde para o ponto 1:

```
// Entre vermelho e verde:
$vermelho = "#ff0000";
$verde = "#00ff00";
echo interpolar_cor_data($vermelho, $data_inicio, $verde, $data_hoje, $data_teste1) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($vermelho, $data_inicio, $verde, $data_hoje, $data_teste2) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($vermelho, $data_inicio, $verde, $data_hoje, $data_teste3) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($vermelho, $data_inicio, $verde, $data_hoje, $data_teste4) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($vermelho, $data_inicio, $verde, $data_hoje, $data_teste5) . "\n";
echo interpolar_cor_data($vermelho, $data_inicio, $verde, $data_hoje, $data_teste6) . "\n";
```

A saída é:

```
#ff0000
#e01e00
#b94500
#6c9200
#1ee000
#00ff00
```

Isso daí se traduz nessas cores: [image: vermelho verde]

[**Veja aqui funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/tHUJ9d)

Answer (score 2):

Opa, acho que consigo te dar uma luz para seu problema.

No exemplo abaixo, eu mandei imprimir um degradê uniforme, mas você pode fazer o seu degradê da forma qual for necessário. Você só precisará ter em mente que será necessário calcular uma taxa de quão perto a data que você quer colorir está da data final, imaginando que a sua data inicial terá valor 0 e sua data final terá valor 1. Então uma data no meio exato entre essas duas terá valor 0,5.

Tendo isso em mente, no exemplo irá imprimir o texto `AAA` colorido da cor referente a essa taxa de distância das cores iniciais e finais.

```
<?php
function getValorDaCor($color) {
    // Assumindo cores no formato #xxxxxx
    return array(
        hexdec(substr($color, 1, 2)),
        hexdec(substr($color, 3, 2)),
        hexdec(substr($color, 5, 2)),
    );
}

function getCorDoValor($array) {
    return sprintf('#%02x%02x%02x', $array[0], $array[1], $array[2]);
}

$cor_inicial = "#ff6347";
$cor_final = "#0066CC";
$valor_cor_inicial = getValorDaCor($cor_inicial); //array
$valor_cor_final = getValorDaCor($cor_final); //array

for( $i=0 ; $i<=1 ; $i+=0.05 ){
    $index = $i; // taxa de quão mais perto da cor final você está

    // Inicio das contas para calcular nova cor
    $novo_valor_1 = array();
    foreach ($valor_cor_inicial as $posicao => $valor) { 
        $novo_valor_1[$posicao] = $index * $valor;
    }

    $novo_valor_2 = array();
    foreach ($valor_cor_final as $posicao => $valor) { 
        $novo_valor_2[$posicao] = (1 - $index) * $valor;
    }

    $newval = array();
    foreach ($novo_valor_1 as $posicao => $valor) { 
        $newval[$posicao] = $valor + $novo_valor_2[$posicao];
    }
    // Fim das contas para calcular nova cor

    $nova_cor = getCorDoValor($newval);

    echo "<span style='color:".$nova_cor."'>AAA</span>";
}

?>
```

Comment: David, sua resposta funcionou, mas a do Victor foi mais simples de implementar pela questão da sua função pedir um array. Mesmo assim, muito obrigado. +1

Comment: @RBZ Por nada, a intensão é ajudar :D